# Cannot find module 'Discord'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm still a beginner at coding and have been trying to run a basic bot on discord. As I've noticed, some things about JavaScript have been changed and cant find any updated tutorial. Now that intents are required I cant seem to find a way to get the bot online without getting the error "Cannot find module 'Discord'". The lines I have so far are:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord ({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
});

client.login('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create an instance of `Discord`, a class which doesn’t exist. You'll have to change it to `Client`.

---

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.login("TOKEN");
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't importing `Discord` from the `discord.js` module, therefore you can't instantiate it.